# How to show somthing when the query is empty?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code to show  "1" if the query is done,How to show "0" when the query is empty.

```
SELECT  1 as 'access' 
FROM  `mytable` 
WHERE  `name` = 'Prophet Muhammad' and id = 1;
```

Comment: How many row that query returns?

Comment: this is mixing GUI and SQL queries... Bad idea, I would say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `COUNT`

```
SELECT  (COUNT(*) >= 1) as 'access' 
FROM    mytable
WHERE   name = 'Prophet Muhammad' and 
        id = 1;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c824b/1)

Comment: If the table has primary key, e.g. pk, `COUNT(pk)` will be much more efficient

Answer (score 1):

You could use this, that shows 1 when the query returns at least one row, and 0 otherwise:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT Null
               FROM  `mytable` 
               WHERE  `name` = 'Prophet Muhammad' and id = 1) as Status
```